# C++ brace initialization for integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, list-initialization

Why does brace-enclosed initialization not work for this integer array?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int arr[2] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

The output is `0 0 -731153664`. Why isn't it `0 0 0`?

Comment: Because an array of `X` elements have indexes from `0` to `X - 1`. The size of the array is the number of elements, not the top index. Something which any book, tutorial or class should have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's only two elements in the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
```

Printing `arr[2]` is undefined behaviour